# How to change specific values in a table created in javascript by pressing a button

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, loops, html-table

Does anyone here know how I can change the value of "list4" when I have created a HTML table like so:

```
var obj = { list1, list2, list3, list4, list5 };
var newArray = [];

  Object.keys(obj).forEach( (o) => newArray.push(obj[o]));

newArray.forEach(function(items) {
var row = document.createElement("tr");
    items.forEach(function(item) {
var cell = document.createElement("td");
    cell.textContent = item;
    row.appendChild(cell);
});
 table.appendChild(row);
});
```

I have extracted the 5 list elements out of a larger array by using this method:

```
var list1 = myArray.map(a => a.list1);
var list2 = myArray.map(a => a.list2);
var list3 = myArray.map(a => a.list3);
var list4 = myArray.map(a => a.list4);
var list5 = myArray.map(a => a.list5);
```

And I would like to change the value of all of the list elements in "list 4" to the existing values divided by 2.2046:

I have made a for-loop and changed the values to the new values:

```
var newValues = myArray.map(a => a.list4);

for (var i = 0; i < newValues.length; i++) {
newValues[i] = (newValues[i]/2.2046).toFixed(1);
}
```

Does anyone know how I can incorporate the last code so that I, by pressing a button with the id="metric", can make all the existing values change to the new values? I thinking maybe innterHTML could help, but I do not know how to get the specific values of list4.. Thank you for any help!

Bonus:
I have tried everything but have not succeeded in turning a string of "5' 6\"" into actual numbers as I also have to change these to metric values, possible anyone here knows?:)   Thank you!

Comment: I added how to get the feet and inches from the string 5' 6" in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Create an array of `cell` elements in the same scope as your list. That way, you write something like `cell[0].textContent = value` whenever you want.

Separate updating the HTML in a new function. Clear the HTML by using `remove()`, then update by using `.appendChild(cell[0])` to add the new values.

As for changing the string to numbers, here is an idea:

```js
let number = "5' 6\"";
let div = document.getElementById("test");
let decimalValue = imperialToDecimal(number);

div.innerHTML = number + " becomes " + decimalValue;

function imperialToDecimal(measurement) {
  let indxFeet = measurement.indexOf("'");
  let indxInches = measurement.indexOf("\"");
  let feet = measurement.substring(0, indxFeet);
  let inches = measurement.substring(indxFeet + 1, indxInches);
  return footAndInchToMeter(feet, inches);
}

function footAndInchToMeter(feet, inches) {
  feet = feet/3.2808;
  inches = inches/39.370;
  return feet + inches;
}
```

```html
<div id="test"></div>
```

This is the basic code that doesn't contain correction for when there is no `'` or `"` symbol (but you can figure that out, I'm sure :).

Comment: Thank you very much!!:) @Denis Do you think you could visualize your answer to the first part like you've done with the feet/inches explanation? I'm very new at JavaScript and having a hard time understanding where I should place your different suggestions.. :)

Comment: @Gilli123 Do you have a specific issue you are struggling with?